Faster method of creating multi-ring buffers in R
I am doing a pretty simple multi-ring buffer landscape analysis in R. The function I am working with is as follows
library(tidyverse)
library(furrr)
plan(multisession, workers = 20)

zonal_analysis <- function(data, raster, buffers, width) {
          data.sf = st_as_sf(data,
                             coords = c('x','y'),
                             crs = "+init=epsg:26911")
          buffers |>
            future_map(~{
                st_difference(
                  st_buffer(data.sf, dist = . + width/2),
                  st_buffer(data.sf, dist = . - width/2)
                )
              }) |>
            map(~{
              zonal(raster,
                    vect(.),
                    fun = mean,
                    as.polygons = TRUE)
            })
}


When I was doing initial tests with overlapping concentric buffers (circles and not rings) performance was completely acceptable, even without reaching for parallelism. As you can see I already tried to alleviate the issue with furrr's parallel implementation, but running this function with 40 buffers still takes a 5-10 minutes to crunch through.
Is there a more efficient way I could be calculating these ring buffers? Perhaps a library with a builtin for this operation or a better implementation on my end?

Can you show how you use this with some sample (even randomly generated) data, and give the approximate size and scope of your application - ie how many buffers and features and the raster size? Is it the buffer creation or the zonal op taking the time?

How many points are in data.sf? Because st_difference is going to work out the differences between all N^2 pairs of the buffer geometries. If there's more than one point then this probably isn't what you want...

Do you need to work in spherical geometry? Because turning off s2 gets you a major speed up. Also, its probably quicker to create a ring by making a circle (as a line from trigonometry) and then doing one buffer operation (both sides of the line). Working with low-level sf objects (ie sfg geometry objects) can also get major speedups, I can get a 20x speedup over the default approach.

You are so right, now that you mention it the fact that st_difference needs to check all pairs is obvious, I will try implementing the buffered circle approach first. I think that will be enough, especially parallelized.

As @Spacedman helpfully reminded me st_difference is O(N^2), a better O(N) way would be to first create a circle, and then buffer that circle by the desired width of the ring. I accomplished this like so:
future_map(buffers, ~{
    st_buffer(data.sf, dist = .) |>
    st_boundary() |>
    st_buffer(dist = width/2)
  },
  .options = furrr_options(seed = 123)
) 

First creating a circle at the right distance away by buffering and extracting the boundary, then buffering the resulting boundary circle to get a ring. This resulted in a monumental speed up, going from 5-10 minutes for 37 rows in data.sf and 41 buffer sizes, to 15-25 seconds (parallelized across 20 workers with furrr)
